# kubernetes API UniversalDeserializer, couldn't get version/kind; json parse error

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, client-go

I am trying to write a validation admission controller webhook which should reject the deployment if No Nodeselector is mentioned,

I am getting this error while creating the deployment -

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "test.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validatingwebhook.kube-system.svc": couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: invalid character '{' after top-level value
```

I have mention the sample code here, to check all the code please visit https://github.com/kumarshivam12/validation-kontroller

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    admissionv1 "k8s.io/api/admission/v1beta1"
    appsv1 "k8s.io/api/apps/v1"
    v1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/serializer"
    "k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/endpoints/handlers/responsewriters"
)

var (
    scheme = runtime.NewScheme()
    codecs = serializer.NewCodecFactory(scheme)
    logger = log.New(os.Stdout, "http: ", log.LstdFlags)
)

func ValidatePod(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Validate that the incoming content type is correct.
    if r.Header.Get("Content-Type") != "application/json" {
        fmt.Println("expected application/json content-type")
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        responsewriters.InternalError(w, r, err)
        fmt.Printf("Error %s, reading the body", err.Error())
    }
    grpversionkind := admissionv1.SchemeGroupVersion.WithKind("AdmissionReview")
    var admissionReview admissionv1.AdmissionReview
    _, _, err = codecs.UniversalDeserializer().Decode(body, &grpversionkind, &admissionReview)
    if err != nil {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("error getting admission review from request: %v", err)
        logger.Printf(msg)
        w.WriteHeader(400)
        w.Write([]byte(msg))
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("debug: %+v\n", admissionReview.Request.Resource)
    var deployment appsv1.Deployment

    _, _, err = codecs.UniversalDeserializer().Decode(body, nil, &deployment)
    if err != nil {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("error getting deployment from request: %v", err)
        logger.Printf(msg)
        w.WriteHeader(400)
        w.Write([]byte(msg))
        return
    }
    resourceNodeselector := deployment.Spec.Template.Spec.NodeSelector

    response := admissionv1.AdmissionResponse{}
    if len(resourceNodeselector) == 0 {
        response = admissionv1.AdmissionResponse{
            UID:     admissionReview.Request.UID,
            Allowed: false,
            Result: &v1.Status{
                Message: fmt.Sprintf("The specified manifest Deployment  %s Does not have the NodeSelector, NodeSelector is Mandatory Field", deployment.Name),
                Status:  "406",
            },
        }
    } else {
        response = admissionv1.AdmissionResponse{
            UID:     admissionReview.Request.UID,
            Allowed: true,
        }
    }
    admissionReview.Response = &response

    res, err := json.Marshal(admissionReview)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error %s, while converting response to byte slice", err.Error())
    }

    _, err = w.Write(res)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error %s, writing respnse to responsewriter", err.Error())
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error %s, while converting response to byte slice", err.Error())
    }

    _, err = w.Write(res)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error %s, writing respnse to responsewriter", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: @shivam I am stuck at similar issue. Where u able to find solution to this?

Comment: Decoding the Body into gvk is not necessary unless you are registering new object kind, you can  do something like 
`admissionReviewRequest := &admissionv1.AdmissionReview{}
 if _, _, err := deserializer.Decode(body, nil, admissionReviewRequest); err != nil {
  sentry.CaptureException(err)
  return nil, err
 }`
then
`admissionReviewRequest, err := admissionReviewFromRequest(r, deserializer)
rawRequest := admissionReviewRequest.Request.Object.Raw
deployment := appsv1.Deployment{}
_, _, err := deserializer.Decode(rawRequest, nil, &deployment)`